# Go func call confusion

Tags: go

In this bit of code:

```
handler := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "<html><body>Hello World!</body></html>")
```

}

What is the `func` keyword doing? I've been reading through the Tour of Go and I'm confused as to what is going on here.

EDITED: Added import list and function that it was apart of

It's part of a function here:

```
func ExampleResponseRecorder() {
handler := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "<html><body>Hello World!</body></html>")
}

req := httptest.NewRequest("GET", "http://example.com/foo", nil)
w := httptest.NewRecorder()
handler(w, req)

resp := w.Result()
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

fmt.Println(resp.StatusCode)
fmt.Println(resp.Header.Get("Content-Type"))
fmt.Println(string(body))

// Output:
// 200
// text/html; charset=utf-8
// <html><body>Hello World!</body></html>
 }

import (
"fmt"
"io"
"io/ioutil"
"log"
"net/http"
"net/http/httptest"
)
```

Comment: See https://golang.org/ref/spec#FunctionLit

Answer (score 3):

`func` defines a [closure](https://gobyexample.com/closures), an annonymous function. `handler` is a variable that holds a reference to this function, which you can later call by passing the arguments in parenthesis:

```
handler(w, req)
```

Comment: Nitpick: an anonymous function is not the same as a closure. This anonymous function does not refer to any variables other than the function variables.